# Advice on Update function in my Game Loop

Tags: java, game, javafx, physics

I have this update fx for my Player object in game loop, game is top-down in-space thing with boom-booms and such. Me being weak at maths is huge understatement so my implementation is concoction of varied tips on internet and help from friend. I was wondering if I could get any tips for implementation while I want to preserve Mass and thrust as a things in equation (to modify variable depending on equipment player as access to).

```
@Override
public void update() {

    // TODO IMPROVE Throttling up and down
    this.ship.cur_thrust = Input.W ? this.ship.max_thrust : 0;

    // TODO IMPROVE Flag checks (Entity.Flag) Immovable reduces need to
    // do calculations altogether.

    // Fnet = m x a :: https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Acceleration
    float accelerationX = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.rotationDeg)) * this.ship.cur_thrust / this.ship.mass; 
    float accelerationY = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.rotationDeg)) * this.ship.cur_thrust / this.ship.mass;

    // vf = v + a*t :: https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Velocity
    this.velocityX += accelerationX * 0.01666f;
    this.velocityY += accelerationY * 0.01666f;

    // toy physics friction speed -= (speed * (1 - friction)) / fps :: 
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990209/game-physics-friction
    // final float FRICTION_FACTOR = 0.50f;

    this.velocityX -= (this.velocityX * (1 - FRICTION_FACTOR)) / 60;
    this.velocityY -= (this.velocityY * (1 - FRICTION_FACTOR)) / 60;

    positionX = positionX + velocityX;
    positionY = positionY + velocityY;

    if (Input.A) this.rotationDeg -= this.ship.torque;
    if (Input.D) this.rotationDeg += this.ship.torque;
    
    if (Input.R) reset();
    if (Input.NUM_1) this.setVehicle(Vehicle.TRAILBLAZER);
    if (Input.NUM_2) this.setVehicle(Vehicle.VANGUARD);
    if (Input.NUM_3) this.setVehicle(Vehicle.BELUGA);
    if (Input.NUM_4) this.setVehicle(Vehicle.EXPLORER);
}
```

first thing that comes to mind is reduce translating Radians to degrees every frame and just hold radian based variable (might be useful also when calculating distances with `atan2()` but I am not sure about drawbacks. I wonder if I can (for purpose of this toy physics implementation) remove some factors and maybe include them as constants skipping calculation there.

I was noticing some 'skipping' movement at lower speeds which is result of precision issue question mark? which I would like to reduce, but am not sure if calculation is wrong or it is just precision thing.

Eventually I would like to extract this thing into `applyForce(float angle, float force)` but before I do that I want to be comfortable with how this function is working and I fully understand what is going on.

UPDATE FOR CONTEXT:

Input.java https://gist.github.com/Catarang1/e8d7e5f7970cd23a4f6b02a3d9b49ff4

Vehicle.java https://gist.github.com/Catarang1/34d9d8579272cddfcf5d5ac982f7ee17

Player.java https://gist.github.com/Catarang1/23b5073fac2d2631ce52ad0095b821b7

AbstractEntity.java https://gist.github.com/Catarang1/49c15e38b1169069f47d126b10bcdbff

thanks for any tips!

Comment: This is likely to get closed as insufficient context.  Please add more code.  In particular, the rest of that class.  Also consider adding `Input`, `Vehicle`, and whatever class `this.ship` is as well as an input/output example.  As is, you just have a bunch of equations with variables of unknown value.

Comment: I dearly hope to see Top-Down In-Space Thing with Boom-Booms on the Steam store.

Comment: @mdfst13 added some context. Mind that I am inexperienced and so my code grows with game instead of my planning ahead. Anything outside update method is temporary solution provided just for context.

Comment: @EricStein Thank you for attempting to help keep the question on-topic, but please refrain from adding the code to the post- [per licensing and other reasons](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/467/120114) the OP must be the one to do that.

Comment: I added every piece of code connected to update method and question got closed for missing review context :D . This community is wild.

Comment: Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB sorry this is frustrating. I just did. Since you advised me on doing so, what did I not upheld as principle when asking question? Because I just wasted 10 minutes of focused thorough reading on something I already knew.

Comment: @JanŠebek Thank you for adding links. [Please embed the code to be reviewed directly in the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/120114). Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself.